# how to open Audio player in android as an intent

Tags: android, audio

I actually trying to open audio player in android , but i didn't get any info about opening audio player . I dont want browse or play the audio song . I just want to open the audio player so any one known this issue please suggest about it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a new intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: music player is not been loaded but the app is getting forceclosed

Answer (score 6):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Note that this action was deprecated in favor of CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC.

Answer (score 2):

here you got your answer: 
 `Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER");`